# Access local/session storage from WebView in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, webview

The website wrapped in the WebView is using OAuth2 authentication and a JWT token is stored in the session/local storage.

If it's possible, how can I access the session/local storage of the website and get the token from the Xamarin part ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IF the JWT is passed back in a header, you can intercept that. I'm not sure the web local storage object/interfaces are exposed directly. Android documentation about that is sparse.

Probably an easier thing to do, which would require a custom renderer, is to have the webview execute some injected javascript to read it from local storage.

Comment: Yes at the end I did that and it worked nice using different Event when needed - e.x. OnPageLoad etc ..